# Raspberry Pi is not found on local network

Tags: networking, wireless

I could connect Raspberry Pi (10.0.1.39), however, I cannot make it found from my Mac (10.0.1.24). I checked that the Firewall is off (by default) on my Mac.

```
smcho@macho ~> ping 10.0.1.39
PING 10.0.1.39 (10.0.1.39): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

arp -a returns with `incomplete` on the Pi's local ip.

```
? (10.0.1.1) at MAC on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.0.1.11) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.0.1.24) at MAC on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (10.0.1.39) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

I can use Internet from Pi (I can ping google.com from Pi), and when I execute `arp -a` from Pi, I get the same (incomplete) message on 10.0.1.24.

What might be wrong? I installed Raspbian with NOOBS (2015-11-21) version.

Comment: How does the RPi get its IP address? Is the address 10.1.0.39 or 10.0.1.39? You have both in your question.

Comment: Checkout [this discussion](http://www.velocityreviews.com/threads/how-can-you-get-an-incomplete-arp.721093/)  on another site, particularly [this post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/threads/how-can-you-get-an-incomplete-arp.721093/#post-5121730) I've tested this and if I ping an unused address on my network arp -a will show it as incomplete. Is your Pi down? Check that you have good power to it.

Comment: If you use static IP for the Pi, check your setting.

Comment: @jogco: There is no power or connection issue with Pi. I don't use static IP, just DHCP. It works well on top of my desk; it's just not found from my mac. I begin to wonder if MAC address is kind of blocked because of some security issues.

Comment: Unless you describe your network architecture (what is connected to what) and list any changes you may have made to network configuration files any comment is idle speculation. `arp` is a waste of time - it only lists established conections.

Answer (score 1):

On your Raspberry Pi, run the command `ifconfig`.

It should give you something like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:08:98:98  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1000 (1000.0 B)  TX bytes:1000 (1000.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:dd:90:4a:50:45  
          inet addr:192.168.0.140  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14990 errors:0 dropped:15296 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2867368 (2.7 MiB)  TX bytes:73259 (71.5 KiB)
```

Look for a local IP address under one of the separated items and look for a local IP address with `inet addr` before it. This should be the local IP address of your Raspberry Pi.

Then head to your MacBook and make sure the checkbox under `System Prefrences > Security > Firewall > Enable Stealth Mode` is disabled. Then, via Terminal type `ping <IP Address>`. Where the 'IP Address' is the IP address of your Raspberry Pi.

Also, you should check that your MacBook and Raspberry Pi are both on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

To save yourself actually having to go to the PI and find its ip address use nmap via the terminal on your MacBook.

This [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/find-raspberry-pi-address-on-local-network) gives an over complicated explanation but it will sort you out providing they are on the same network.