# Raspberry pi 3 boot issues

Tags: boot

Got a new Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm trying to use it with my Mac. I formatted the SD card and downloaded NOOBS. The green light comes on sometimes but when I add this to terminal:

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

I get this error message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Please advise.

Comment: You NEED to setup NOOBS with a keyboard and screen- it can't be done with ssh

Comment: Putting ```ssh``` in ```/boot``` doesn't work?

Comment: Milliways is absolutely correct.  Plus, you issued a ssh command to a hostname, but didn't mention whether or not that hostname would even be in your hosts file or DNS.  Even when you get through the setup (using a monitor and keyboard) and give it a hostname, you will still need to address it by IP address until all the rest is set up.

Comment: Thank you Milliways and SD solar for your suggestion.. so I tried connecting to TV and the screen showed up but now my mouse and keyboard won't work... trying a different power adapter today

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things...

1. With NOOBS the initial setup has to be done with a directly connected keyboard and display, `ssh` isn't an option. So you'll either need to set that up or pick an OS for your initial install. I've been having good luck with Raspbian Stretch which you can download [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).
2. Then, in the root of the SD card, you'll need to put a file named `ssh` – it can be empty. Just mount the card on your Mac, the SD card will show up in Devices in Finder and will probably be called `boot` – then it Terminal do:

   `touch /Volumes/boot/ssh`

   If the SD card isn't called `boot` substitute the name you see in Finder.
3. Then eject the card and put it back in the Pi and reboot the Pi.
4. Next you need to figure out what IP address the Pi has been assigned. I'm assuming that it is "headless" so you can't just watch the console. That would be too easy... So, take a look at this question: [Find Raspberry PI address on local network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/find-raspberry-pi-address-on-local-network), my favorite method is to `ping` the broadcast address on the network (`X.Y.Z.255`) then use `arp -a | grep B8`.
5. Once you connect to the Pi run the `raspi-config` command and permanently enable `ssh` it is under Option 5, Interfacing Options. As I understand it, the trick in step 1 is a one-time thing.

[image: Contents of Raspbian Stretch SD root]