# Can't find a Raspberry via hostname from another Raspberry

Tags: raspbian, networking, ping

What I want to do is simple: I have changed a raspberry hostname to something different from raspberrypi and I want to ping this raspberry from another raspberry via its new hostname. What happens is that, for some reason, raspberry can't find other raspberries via ping, and I know the hostname change works because I can ping this renamed raspberry from my PC. Is there anything I can do change this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Raspberry PI address on local network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/find-raspberry-pi-address-on-local-network)

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .local to the end of your pi name.

```
ping raspberrypi.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
avahi-browse -at
```

(you may need to install `avahi-utils` for this)

this will give you a list of devices that can be found. For example, one of my Pi`s appears as

```
+   eth0 IPv4 phi [b8:27:eb:c0:55:47]         Workstation          local
```

That means I can see  the Pi as `phi.local`.