# Programmatically SSH into pi on local network without looking up IP-Address beforehand?

Tags: networking, ssh, connection, static-ip

I have a pi in my local network, and I sometimes want to connect to it via ssh. However, the pi always has a different IP-address, so I look it up beforehand each and every time. Is there a way for me to connect to my pi without looking up it's IP address? I could assign a static IP in my local network, but I'm not sure if that's good practice or whether there are better solutions. If there aren't, it would be great if s.b. could explain how to assign a static IP to my pi in my local network. Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: I am looking to connect to my pi via ssh programmatically. So a software solution that finds the IP address might not do.

Comment: Have you tried `hostname.local`? Some routers also use .local domain (`hostname.local`).

Comment: I know it has been solved already, but for completeness: That last bit of my comment above should have read `.home`: `hostname.home`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Raspberry Pi's IP address for SSH](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/how-to-get-the-raspberry-pis-ip-address-for-ssh) or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12440/78211 or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38/78211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you've changed some settings on your Pi or not, but recent "stock" Raspbian will have the [Avahi](https://avahi.org/) service installed & configured for the SSH server. All being well you should be able to say `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` from within the local network, where `raspberrypi` is the hostname you've given your Pi, and connect.

If it's not set up on your Pi then you can follow the instructions on eLinux [here](https://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup#Setting_up_for_remote_access_.2F_headless_operation) to get it working: the Avahi stuff is a little bit further down after the section on assigning a static IP (which you can follow instead if you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

in the terminal : sudo raspi-config
then with 'N1 hostname' give the name you want to your pi : mypi
reboot
then you can connect in ssh with :
ssh pi@mypi.local

Comment: @R.Kohlisch An unmodified Raspbian image comes with hostname `raspberrypi`. Why it does not work with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`?